# At what point should a HDD be replaced?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I am getting a warning for `pending sector count` and shrinking the partition to create a second one failed several times. There are no visible signs beside that. `chkdsk` didn't change anything.
Should I worry that the HDD could fail very soon, or can it hold like this for years ?
I don't understand why `pending` doesn't become `reallocated`..

[image]

Comment: Reallocated sectors are normal for aging drives, there are plenty of spare sectors, its only when they get over 100 reallocated sectors that the drive will fail soon, I would replace the drive and use it for extra storage for non critical data.

Comment: The disk is quite old, but it has only a bit over a year of full time work on it. Usually it's at 40k work hours that age starts to show. I think it was powered off suddenly or dropped and i can't reallocate that pending sector.

Answer (score 2):

I replace drives like this right away. They may be OK for a short while but errors continue to increase and it may die when you least expect it to die.

*can it hold like this for years ?*  Not very likely at all